# firebase ios chat app not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableViewController that has a list of messages the logged in user has had with any user of his/her choice. When the cell is clicked, it should go to a view controller that allows the logged in user to chat any user. I have set up an override segue:

```
var userpicuid: String?
var username: String?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         let message = messages[indexPath.row]

        if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
            var newVariable = message.ReceiverId

            if self.userpicuid ==  newVariable {

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid!)

                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                    in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                        for post in dictionary {
                            let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                            for (id, value) in messages {

                                self.username = messages["username"] as? String


                            }}}})}} else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
            let newVariable = message.senderId

            if self.userpicuid ==  newVariable {

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid!)

                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                    in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                        for post in dictionary {
                            let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                            for (id, value) in messages {

                                self.username = messages["username"] as? String
                            }}}})}

        }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "MessageNow", sender: self.userpicuid)

}


override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
        return
    }

    chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
    chatVc.receiverData = sender as AnyObject
    chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
    chatVc.username = self.username

}
```

And in the destination view controller,this is the setup:

```
var receiverData: AnyObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.senderId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

 let receiverId = receiverData as! String
        let receiverIdFive = String(receiverId.characters.prefix(5))
        let senderIdFive = String(senderId.characters.prefix(5))
        if (senderIdFive > receiverIdFive)
        {
            self.convoId = senderIdFive + receiverIdFive
        }
        else
        {
            self.convoId = receiverIdFive + senderIdFive
        }}
```

I get the error Could not cast value of type 'Lit_Swap.MessageTableViewCell' (0x1091d0f10) to 'NSString' (0x10b153c60). because the sender is apparently a tableviewcell, how will I set up the sender so it allows me to click on the cell and segue into the chat controller.

Comment: It would help to know specifically what line is causing the error. Setting a break point and manually stepping through line by line would reveal the line with the error. However, I suspect this line *chatVc.receiverData = sender as AnyObject* which assigns the sender as a value, which doesn't really match up with this line *let receiverId = receiverData as! String*

Comment: @Jay the line cause the error is `let receiverId = receiverData as! String`

Comment: Right. Per my comment. You can't assign *sender* to string as it's a different class. *(override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {(*

Comment: @Jay what is the correct way to assign my sender in order for me to segue to the chat view controller?

Comment: I posted an answer that may provide another option for segue'ing but  Any should be a String so *chatVc.receiverData = sender as! String* would be going the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to move data between views, one is a segue and there are a number of options for segue'ing as well.

Here's one using a representedObject property

Say we have a view controller with a textField and a button that triggers the action of the secondSheetController

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var sourceTextField: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let second = segue.destinationController as! SecondController
       second.representedObject = self.myTextField.text
   }
}
```

And the viewController we are segue'ing to

```
class SecondController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var targetTextField: NSTextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func viewWillAppear() {
       self.targetTextField.text = self.representedObject as! String
   }
}
```

additionally, to address the question if the sender is a String and we don't want to use the representedObject property, an assignment to String would be a solution.

```
chatVc.receiverData = sender as! String
```

as a third option, any class vars in the SecondController could be directly set

```
class SecondController: NSViewController {
   var option1 = ""
   var option2 = ""
```

then from the first view controller

```
secondController.option1 = "look kids, Parliament, Big Ben"
secondController.option2 = "Don't call me Shirley"
```

Comment: could you please, if you can explain to me why doing this `@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMessageToUser", sender: self.userpicuid)
    }` in another view controller with the exact same override public function in my question works.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but *sender: Any?* vs *sender: self.userpicuid* is a significant difference. *Any* is Any object (undefined at the moment) whereas *uidpicid* is a String.

Comment: so essentially I want to pass the string self.userpicuid  so I changed chatvc.receiverdata to `chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid` and in the chatviewcintroller I set  `var receiverData: String?` and `let receiverId = receiverData!` but now I receive the error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @juelizabeth We'll, that would mean that one of your variables that shouldn't be nil, is in fact, nil. You've defined *receiverData* as an optional string so it could be optionally nil and if so, that error would make sense. I would suggest adding some print statements to see where and when your variable is nil. It's a shot in the dark though without seeing your code. Perhaps another question as to why it's nil would be in order?

Comment: is there a way you can take a look at my code, I have been struggling with this for over a week

Comment: @juelizabeth You can post a project on a service like GitHub. If it's a small amount of code, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: its actually not a small amount of code. I put print statements in various places like you told me and turns out username and userpicuid come out nil

Comment: @juelizabeth That's a good start. So you need to backtrack to determine why those are nil. You can probably troubleshoot from there but if not, post another question with the minimal code to reproduce the issue and we will take a look. If my answer and comments helped, remember to accept it so it can help others!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UINavigatorcontroll. You could try this solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedConversation = conversationArray[indexPath.row]
    showConversationMessages(conversation: selectedConversation)
}


func showConversationMessages(conversation: ConversationItem){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesVC
    vc.receiverId = conversation.idMessagePartner
    vc.receiverToken = conversation.receiverToken
    vc.receiverUserName = conversation.userDisplayName
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

`ConversationItem` is my class for holding the data I need.

Then you can use the variables in you second controller which I have named `MessageVC` in my example.

```
class MessagesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {
    private let TAG = "MessagesVC"

    var receiverId: Int64 = 0
    var receiverToken: String = ""
    var receiverUserName: String = ""

  ....
```

I've never really worked with `override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` but I do see a lot of people having problems with it.